# Java Dynamic Casting Object to List<?>

Tags: java

I have a situation to where I need to cast `Object` to `List<SomeClassName>`.

I get the object value `List<SomeClass>` from request parameter.

I need to cast this `Object` into `List<SomeClass>`. I don't know the `SomeClass` at compile time.

I can get the class type at run time as `String`.

Sample:

```java
private static Object createList(Object object){

      List dd = (List)object;

      //the List contains the objects of this class
      Class cls = Class.forName(dd.get(0).getClass().getName());

      //I would like to cast this Object to List<thisClass>
}
```

for example the class is `jp.Dto.UserDto` then the casting should be like `List<jp.dto.UserDto> list = (List<jp.dto.UserDto>)Object;` but the problem here is I don't know `jp.dto.UserDto` class at compile time. I can get this at run time only.

How this can be achieved?

Comment: this is not enough code to understand what you are trying to do. Are you going to return the list as an object again? are you going to iterate over all the lists in the same manner? why are you passing around objects instead of strongly typed Lists. I think, the general idea you might be looking for are generics (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java)

Comment: My requirment
using java reflection i need to get the list values,and wants to itrate through the loop.Using reflection API i can get only the objects..So after getting the object value of the list property.i want to itrate the list values...

Answer (score 11):

Basically, which I not really recommend, you can do something like this, the type restriction is not even necessary:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object list = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Integer> integers = cast(list);
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T extends List<?>> T cast(Object obj) {
    return (T) obj;
}
```

It also shows the problem it introduces

Comment: Instead of List<integer>, i need to cast List<UserDto> userList,this user Dto calas has some property like userId,userName,How can i access these property values from this list.            userList.get(0)

Answer (score 3):

You should understand that Generics in Java i.e. the stuff between <> is erased at runtime, so declaring a list like the following is perfectly legal.

```
List list = (List)someObject;
```

furthermore adding objects to this list like the following is also permitted

```
list.add(someObjectOfACertainClass);
```

From what I understand you are being passed an object which is a list of objects of a certain class and you want to iterate through that list in a compile time type safe manner. You can do something like the following:

```
private static <T> Object createList(List<T> argumentList) {
    List<T> otherList = new ArrayList<T>();
    //do something here
    return otherList;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add object to your list:

```
List<FuelLoading> objList=new ArrayList<>();
                            objList.add(new FuelLoading(String.valueOf(vehicleId), String.valueOf(driverId), String.valueOf(fuelN), fillingDate, fillingTk, fillingM, userId));
```